# Getting a long avrdude error while uploading a simple sketch to arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno, avrdude

This is the error which shows up after the sketch is compiled and starts uploading.

Is there some sort of fix to this problem?

There are no shields connected to it, not even I/O pins are being used, just trying the simple Blink sketch.

NOTE : It was working find before and then it started acting crazy

```
    Binary sketch size: 1,084 bytes (of a 32,256 byte maximum)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -v -v -v -patmega328p -carduino -P\\.\COM3 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:G:\Temp\build5658632448223358877.tmp\Blink.cpp.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 19:38:36
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : \\.\COM3
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
         AVR Part                      : ATMEGA328P
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PC2
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : Arduino
         Description     : Arduino
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [80]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [81]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [04] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [82]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [04] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [98]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
         Hardware Version: 3
         Firmware Version: 4.4
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [84]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [85]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [86]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [87]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [89]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [03] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
         Vtarget         : 0.3 V
         Varef           : 0.3 V
         Oscillator      : 28.800 kHz
         SCK period      : 3.3 us

avrdude: Send: A [41] . [81]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [04] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: A [41] . [82]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [04] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: B [42] . [86] . [00] . [00] . [01] . [01] . [01] . [01] . [03] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [ff] . [00] . [80] . [04] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [80] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: E [45] . [05] . [04] . [d7] . [c2] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: P [50]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | avrdude: Send: u [75]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] . [1e] . [95] . [0f] . [10] 
################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e950f
avrdude: Send: V [56] . [a0] . [03] . [fc] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: V [56] . [a0] . [03] . [fd] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: V [56] . [a0] . [03] . [fe] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: V [56] . [a0] . [03] . [ff] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: reading input file "G:\Temp\build5658632448223358877.tmp\Blink.cpp.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (1084 bytes):

Writing | avrdude: Send: U [55] . [00] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [0c] . [94] a [61] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] . [9d] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] $ [24] . [00] ' [27] . [00] * [2a] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] % [25] . [00] ( [28] . [00] + [2b] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
#####avrdude: Send: U [55] @ [40] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] # [23] . [00] & [26] . [00] ) [29] . [00] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [02] . [02] . [02] . [02] . [02] . [02] . [03] . [03] . [03] . [03] . [03] . [03] . [01] . [02] . [04] . [08] . [10]   [20] @ [40] . [80] . [01] . [02] . [04] . [08] . [10]   [20] . [01] . [02] . [04] . [08] . [10]   [20] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [07] . [00] . [02] . [01] . [00] . [00] . [03] . [04] . [06] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [11] $ [24] . [1f] . [be] . [cf] . [ef] . [d8] . [e0] . [de] . [bf] . [cd] . [bf] . [11] . [e0] . [a0] . [e0] . [b1] . [e0] . [ea] . [e3] . [f4] . [e0] . [02] . [c0] . [05] . [90] . [0d] . [92] . [a2] 0 [30] . [b1] . [07] . [d9] . [f7] . [11] . [e0] . [a2] . [e0] . [b1] . [e0] . [01] . [c0] . [1d] . [92] . [ab] 0 [30] . [b1] . [07] . [e1] . [f7] . [0e] . [94] . [0c] . [02] . [0c] . [94] . [1b] . [02] . [0c] . [94] . [00] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [80] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [80] . [91] . [00] . [01] a [61] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [b8] . [01] h [68] . [ee] s [73] . [e0] . [80] . [e0] . [90] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [e5] . [00] . [80] . [91] . [00] . [01] ` [60] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [b8] . [01] h [68] . [ee] s [73] . [e0] . [80] . [e0] . [90] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [e5] . [00] . [08] . [95] . [80] . [91] . [00] . [01] a [61] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] y [79] . [01] . [08] . [95] . [1f] . [92] . [0f] . [92] . [0f] . [b6] . [0f] . [92] . [11] $ [24] / [2f] . [93] ? [3f] . [93] . [8f] . [93] . [9f] . [93] . [af] . [93] . [bf] . [93] . [80] . [91] . [06] . [01] . [90] . [91] . [07] . [01] . [a0] . [91] . [08] . [01] . [b0] . [91] . [09] . [01] 0 [30] . [91] . [0a] . [01] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] # [23] / [2f] - [2d] _ [5f] - [2d] 7 [37]   [20] . [f0] - [2d] W [57] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d]   [20] . [93] . [0a] . [01] . [80] . [93]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [c0] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [06] . [01] . [90] . [93] . [07] . [01] . [a0] . [93] . [08] . [01] . [b0] . [93] . [09] . [01] . [80] . [91] . [02] . [01] . [90] . [91] . [03] . [01] . [a0] . [91] . [04] . [01] . [b0] . [91] . [05] . [01] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] . [80] . [93] . [02] . [01] . [90] . [93] . [03] . [01] . [a0] . [93] . [04] . [01] . [b0] . [93] . [05] . [01] . [bf] . [91] . [af] . [91] . [9f] . [91] . [8f] . [91] ? [3f] . [91] / [2f] . [91] . [0f] . [90] . [0f] . [be] . [0f] . [90] . [1f] . [90] . [18] . [95] . [9b] . [01] . [ac] . [01] . [7f] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [80] . [91] . [02] . [01] . [90] . [91] . [03] . [01] . [a0] . [91] . [04] . [01] . [b0] . [91] . [05] . [01] f [66] . [b5] . [a8] . [9b] . [05] . [c0] o [6f] ? [3f] . [19] . [f0] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] . [7f] . [bf] . [ba] / [2f] . [a9] / [2f] . [98] / [2f] . [88] ' [27] . [86] . [0f] . [91] . [1d]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [00] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] b [62] . [e0] . [88] . [0f] . [99] . [1f] . [aa] . [1f] . [bb] . [1f] j [6a] . [95] . [d1] . [f7] . [bc] . [01] - [2d] . [c0] . [ff] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [80] . [91] . [02] . [01] . [90] . [91] . [03] . [01] . [a0] . [91] . [04] . [01] . [b0] . [91] . [05] . [01] . [e6] . [b5] . [a8] . [9b] . [05] . [c0] . [ef] ? [3f] . [19] . [f0] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] . [ff] . [bf] . [ba] / [2f] . [a9] / [2f] . [98] / [2f] . [88] ' [27] . [8e] . [0f] . [91] . [1d] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] . [e2] . [e0] . [88] . [0f] . [99] . [1f] . [aa] . [1f] . [bb] . [1f] . [ea] . [95] . [d1] . [f7] . [86] . [1b] . [97] . [0b] . [88] ^ [5e] . [93] @ [40] . [c8] . [f2] ! [21] P [50] 0 [30] @ [40] @ [40] @ [40] P [50] @ [40] h [68] Q [51] | [7c] O [4f] ! [21] . [15] 1 [31] . [05] A [41] . [05] Q [51] . [05] q [71] . [f6] . [08] . [95] x [78] . [94] . [84] . [b5]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] @ [40] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [82] ` [60] . [84] . [bd] . [84] . [b5] . [81] ` [60] . [84] . [bd] . [85] . [b5] . [82] ` [60] . [85] . [bd] . [85] . [b5] . [81] ` [60] . [85] . [bd] . [ee] . [e6] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [e1] . [e8] . [f0] . [e0] . [10] . [82] . [80] . [81] . [82] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [e0] . [e8] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [e1] . [eb] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [84] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [e0] . [eb] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [ea] . [e7] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [84] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [80] . [81] . [82] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [80] . [81] . [80] h [68] . [80] . [83] . [10] . [92] . [c1] . [00] . [08] . [95] . [cf] . [93] . [df] . [93] H [48] / [2f] P [50] . [e0] . [ca] . [01] . [86] V [56] . [9f] O [4f]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [80] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [fc] . [01] 4 [34] . [91] J [4a] W [57] _ [5f] O [4f] . [fa] . [01] . [84] . [91] . [88] # [23] i [69] . [f1] . [90] . [e0] . [88] . [0f] . [99] . [1f] . [fc] . [01] . [e8] Y [59] . [ff] O [4f] . [a5] . [91] . [b4] . [91] . [fc] . [01] . [ee] X [58] . [ff] O [4f] . [c5] . [91] . [d4] . [91] f [66] # [23] Q [51] . [f4] / [2f] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [8c] . [91] . [93] / [2f] . [90] . [95] . [89] # [23] . [8c] . [93] . [88] . [81] . [89] # [23] . [0b] . [c0] b [62] 0 [30] a [61] . [f4] / [2f] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [8c] . [91] . [93] / [2f] . [90] . [95] . [89] # [23] . [8c] . [93] . [88] . [81] . [83] + [2b] . [88] . [83] / [2f] . [bf] . [06] . [c0] . [9f] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [8c] . [91] . [83] + [2b] . [8c] . [93] . [9f] . [bf] . [df] . [91] . [cf] . [91] . [08] . [95] H [48] / [2f] P [50] . [e0] . [ca] . [01] . [82] U [55] . [9f] O [4f] . [fc] . [01] $ [24] . [91] . [ca] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [c0] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] . [80] F [46] . [86] V [56] . [9f] O [4f] . [fc] . [01] . [94] . [91] J [4a] W [57] _ [5f] O [4f] . [fa] . [01] 4 [34] . [91] 3 [33] # [23] . [09] . [f4] @ [40] . [c0] " [22] # [23] Q [51] . [f1] # [23] 0 [30] q [71] . [f0] $ [24] 0 [30] ( [28] . [f4] ! [21] 0 [30] . [a1] . [f0] " [22] 0 [30] . [11] . [f5] . [14] . [c0] & [26] 0 [30] . [b1] . [f0] ' [27] 0 [30] . [c1] . [f0] $ [24] 0 [30] . [d9] . [f4] . [04] . [c0] . [80] . [91] . [80] . [00] . [8f] w [77] . [03] . [c0] . [80] . [91] . [80] . [00] . [8f] } [7d] . [80] . [93] . [80] . [00] . [10] . [c0] . [84] . [b5] . [8f] w [77] . [02] . [c0] . [84] . [b5] . [8f] } [7d] . [84] . [bd] . [09] . [c0] . [80] . [91] . [b0] . [00] . [8f] w [77] . [03] . [c0] . [80] . [91] . [b0] . [00] . [8f] } [7d] . [80] . [93] . [b0] . [00] . [e3] / [2f] . [f0] . [e0] . [ee] . [0f] . [ff] . [1f] . [ee] X [58] . [ff] O [4f] . [a5] . [91] . [b4] . [91] / [2f] . [b7]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [00] . [02]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: d [64] . [00] < [3c] F [46] . [f8] . [94] f [66] # [23] ! [21] . [f4] . [8c] . [91] . [90] . [95] . [89] # [23] . [02] . [c0] . [8c] . [91] . [89] + [2b] . [8c] . [93] / [2f] . [bf] . [08] . [95] . [cf] . [93] . [df] . [93] . [0e] . [94] > [3e] . [01] . [0e] . [94] . [97] . [00] . [c0] . [e0] . [d0] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [80] . [00]   [20] . [97] . [e1] . [f3] . [0e] . [94] . [00] . [00] . [f9] . [cf] . [f8] . [94] . [ff] . [cf] . [0d] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
### | 100% 0.27s

avrdude: 1084 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against G:\Temp\build5658632448223358877.tmp\Blink.cpp.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file G:\Temp\build5658632448223358877.tmp\Blink.cpp.hex:
avrdude: input file G:\Temp\build5658632448223358877.tmp\Blink.cpp.hex contains 1084 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | avrdude: Send: U [55] . [00] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [0c] . [94] a [61] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] . [9d] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [0c] . [94] ~ [7e] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] $ [24] . [00] ' [27] . [00] * [2a] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] % [25] . [00] ( [28] . [00] + [2b] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
#####avrdude: Send: U [55] @ [40] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: # [23] . [00] & [26] . [00] ) [29] . [00] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [04] . [02] . [02] . [02] . [02] . [02] . [02] . [03] . [03] . [03] . [03] . [03] . [03] . [01] . [02] . [04] . [08] . [10]   [20] @ [40] . [80] . [01] . [02] . [04] . [08] . [10]   [20] . [01] . [02] . [04] . [08] . [10]   [20] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [07] . [00] . [02] . [01] . [00] . [00] . [03] . [04] . [06] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [00] . [11] $ [24] . [1f] . [be] . [cf] . [ef] . [d8] . [e0] . [de] . [bf] . [cd] . [bf] . [11] . [e0] . [a0] . [e0] . [b1] . [e0] . [ea] . [e3] . [f4] . [e0] . [02] . [c0] . [05] . [90] . [0d] . [92] . [a2] 0 [30] . [b1] . [07] . [d9] . [f7] . [11] . [e0] . [a2] . [e0] . [b1] . [e0] . [01] . [c0] . [1d] . [92] . [ab] 0 [30] . [b1] . [07] . [e1] . [f7] . [0e] . [94] . [0c] . [02] . [0c] . [94] . [1b] . [02] . [0c] . [94] . [00] . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [80] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [80] . [91] . [00] . [01] a [61] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [b8] . [01] h [68] . [ee] s [73] . [e0] . [80] . [e0] . [90] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [e5] . [00] . [80] . [91] . [00] . [01] ` [60] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [b8] . [01] h [68] . [ee] s [73] . [e0] . [80] . [e0] . [90] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [e5] . [00] . [08] . [95] . [80] . [91] . [00] . [01] a [61] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] y [79] . [01] . [08] . [95] . [1f] . [92] . [0f] . [92] . [0f] . [b6] . [0f] . [92] . [11] $ [24] / [2f] . [93] ? [3f] . [93] . [8f] . [93] . [9f] . [93] . [af] . [93] . [bf] . [93] . [80] . [91] . [06] . [01] . [90] . [91] . [07] . [01] . [a0] . [91] . [08] . [01] . [b0] . [91] . [09] . [01] 0 [30] . [91] . [0a] . [01] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] # [23] / [2f] - [2d] _ [5f] - [2d] 7 [37]   [20] . [f0] - [2d] W [57] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d]   [20] . [93] . [0a] . [01] . [80] . [93] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [c0] . [00]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [06] . [01] . [90] . [93] . [07] . [01] . [a0] . [93] . [08] . [01] . [b0] . [93] . [09] . [01] . [80] . [91] . [02] . [01] . [90] . [91] . [03] . [01] . [a0] . [91] . [04] . [01] . [b0] . [91] . [05] . [01] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] . [80] . [93] . [02] . [01] . [90] . [93] . [03] . [01] . [a0] . [93] . [04] . [01] . [b0] . [93] . [05] . [01] . [bf] . [91] . [af] . [91] . [9f] . [91] . [8f] . [91] ? [3f] . [91] / [2f] . [91] . [0f] . [90] . [0f] . [be] . [0f] . [90] . [1f] . [90] . [18] . [95] . [9b] . [01] . [ac] . [01] . [7f] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [80] . [91] . [02] . [01] . [90] . [91] . [03] . [01] . [a0] . [91] . [04] . [01] . [b0] . [91] . [05] . [01] f [66] . [b5] . [a8] . [9b] . [05] . [c0] o [6f] ? [3f] . [19] . [f0] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] . [7f] . [bf] . [ba] / [2f] . [a9] / [2f] . [98] / [2f] . [88] ' [27] . [86] . [0f] . [91] . [1d] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [00] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] b [62] . [e0] . [88] . [0f] . [99] . [1f] . [aa] . [1f] . [bb] . [1f] j [6a] . [95] . [d1] . [f7] . [bc] . [01] - [2d] . [c0] . [ff] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [80] . [91] . [02] . [01] . [90] . [91] . [03] . [01] . [a0] . [91] . [04] . [01] . [b0] . [91] . [05] . [01] . [e6] . [b5] . [a8] . [9b] . [05] . [c0] . [ef] ? [3f] . [19] . [f0] . [01] . [96] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] . [ff] . [bf] . [ba] / [2f] . [a9] / [2f] . [98] / [2f] . [88] ' [27] . [8e] . [0f] . [91] . [1d] . [a1] . [1d] . [b1] . [1d] . [e2] . [e0] . [88] . [0f] . [99] . [1f] . [aa] . [1f] . [bb] . [1f] . [ea] . [95] . [d1] . [f7] . [86] . [1b] . [97] . [0b] . [88] ^ [5e] . [93] @ [40] . [c8] . [f2] ! [21] P [50] 0 [30] @ [40] @ [40] @ [40] P [50] @ [40] h [68] Q [51] | [7c] O [4f] ! [21] . [15] 1 [31] . [05] A [41] . [05] Q [51] . [05] q [71] . [f6] . [08] . [95] x [78] . [94] . [84] . [b5] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] @ [40] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [82] ` [60] . [84] . [bd] . [84] . [b5] . [81] ` [60] . [84] . [bd] . [85] . [b5] . [82] ` [60] . [85] . [bd] . [85] . [b5] . [81] ` [60] . [85] . [bd] . [ee] . [e6] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [e1] . [e8] . [f0] . [e0] . [10] . [82] . [80] . [81] . [82] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [e0] . [e8] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [e1] . [eb] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [84] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [e0] . [eb] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [ea] . [e7] . [f0] . [e0] . [80] . [81] . [84] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [80] . [81] . [82] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [80] . [81] . [81] ` [60] . [80] . [83] . [80] . [81] . [80] h [68] . [80] . [83] . [10] . [92] . [c1] . [00] . [08] . [95] . [cf] . [93] . [df] . [93] H [48] / [2f] P [50] . [e0] . [ca] . [01] . [86] V [56] . [9f] O [4f] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [80] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [fc] . [01] 4 [34] . [91] J [4a] W [57] _ [5f] O [4f] . [fa] . [01] . [84] . [91] . [88] # [23] i [69] . [f1] . [90] . [e0] . [88] . [0f] . [99] . [1f] . [fc] . [01] . [e8] Y [59] . [ff] O [4f] . [a5] . [91] . [b4] . [91] . [fc] . [01] . [ee] X [58] . [ff] O [4f] . [c5] . [91] . [d4] . [91] f [66] # [23] Q [51] . [f4] / [2f] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [8c] . [91] . [93] / [2f] . [90] . [95] . [89] # [23] . [8c] . [93] . [88] . [81] . [89] # [23] . [0b] . [c0] b [62] 0 [30] a [61] . [f4] / [2f] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [8c] . [91] . [93] / [2f] . [90] . [95] . [89] # [23] . [8c] . [93] . [88] . [81] . [83] + [2b] . [88] . [83] / [2f] . [bf] . [06] . [c0] . [9f] . [b7] . [f8] . [94] . [8c] . [91] . [83] + [2b] . [8c] . [93] . [9f] . [bf] . [df] . [91] . [cf] . [91] . [08] . [95] H [48] / [2f] P [50] . [e0] . [ca] . [01] . [82] U [55] . [9f] O [4f] . [fc] . [01] $ [24] . [91] . [ca] . [01] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [c0] . [01]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] . [80] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [86] V [56] . [9f] O [4f] . [fc] . [01] . [94] . [91] J [4a] W [57] _ [5f] O [4f] . [fa] . [01] 4 [34] . [91] 3 [33] # [23] . [09] . [f4] @ [40] . [c0] " [22] # [23] Q [51] . [f1] # [23] 0 [30] q [71] . [f0] $ [24] 0 [30] ( [28] . [f4] ! [21] 0 [30] . [a1] . [f0] " [22] 0 [30] . [11] . [f5] . [14] . [c0] & [26] 0 [30] . [b1] . [f0] ' [27] 0 [30] . [c1] . [f0] $ [24] 0 [30] . [d9] . [f4] . [04] . [c0] . [80] . [91] . [80] . [00] . [8f] w [77] . [03] . [c0] . [80] . [91] . [80] . [00] . [8f] } [7d] . [80] . [93] . [80] . [00] . [10] . [c0] . [84] . [b5] . [8f] w [77] . [02] . [c0] . [84] . [b5] . [8f] } [7d] . [84] . [bd] . [09] . [c0] . [80] . [91] . [b0] . [00] . [8f] w [77] . [03] . [c0] . [80] . [91] . [b0] . [00] . [8f] } [7d] . [80] . [93] . [b0] . [00] . [e3] / [2f] . [f0] . [e0] . [ee] . [0f] . [ff] . [1f] . [ee] X [58] . [ff] O [4f] . [a5] . [91] . [b4] . [91] / [2f] . [b7] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
######avrdude: Send: U [55] . [00] . [02]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
avrdude: Send: t [74] . [00] < [3c] F [46]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [f8] . [94] f [66] # [23] ! [21] . [f4] . [8c] . [91] . [90] . [95] . [89] # [23] . [02] . [c0] . [8c] . [91] . [89] + [2b] . [8c] . [93] / [2f] . [bf] . [08] . [95] . [cf] . [93] . [df] . [93] . [0e] . [94] > [3e] . [01] . [0e] . [94] . [97] . [00] . [c0] . [e0] . [d0] . [e0] . [0e] . [94] . [80] . [00]   [20] . [97] . [e1] . [f3] . [0e] . [94] . [00] . [00] . [f9] . [cf] . [f8] . [94] . [ff] . [cf] . [0d] . [00] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 
### | 100% 0.20s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: 1084 bytes of flash verified
avrdude: Send: Q [51]   [20] 
avrdude: Recv: . [14] 
avrdude: Recv: . [10] 

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Comment: Did you try turning verbose output off?

Comment: Actually that did work, Thanks ;) But is there something wrong with the arduino and what does the verbose mean ? THanks

Comment: I see no error in this output. I can just that avrdude was called with `-v -v -v -v` which tells it to be very verbose. You have to remove that option (IIRC you can do this in Arduino IDE preferences dialog, otherwise you can take a look at `avrdude.conf` file , find this option and change it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error. AVRDude is running with the Verbose flag on. Verbose in English means:

> using or expressed in more words than are needed.

In the Arduino IDE:

[image: Running with the Verbose flag.]